# Diego Installation - Error when generating manifest with spiff merge

Tags: cloud-foundry

When "generating manifest" by running:

```
 spiff merge   input/config-from-cf.yml   input/config-from-cf-internal.yml   input/cf-deployment.yml   > output/config-from-cf.yml
```

I get the following error. What is it that I am doing wrong? It looks like the nodes are included in the last file. Why are they not resolving?

```
error generating manifest: unresolved nodes:
(( properties.cc.internal_api_password ))       in dynaml       config_from_cf.cc.internal_api_password ()
        (( properties.cc.srv_api_uri )) in dynaml       config_from_cf.cc.srv_api_uri   ()
        (( properties.cc.staging_upload_password ))     in dynaml       config_from_cf.cc.staging_upload_password       ()
        (( properties.cc.staging_upload_user )) in dynaml       config_from_cf.cc.staging_upload_user   ()
        (( name ))      in dynaml       config_from_cf.cf_deployment_name       ()
        (( properties.consul.agent.servers.lan ))       in dynaml       config_from_cf.consul.lan_servers       ()
        (( properties.consul.agent.log_level )) in dynaml       config_from_cf.consul.log_level ()
        (( properties.etcd.machines ))  in dynaml       config_from_cf.etcd.machines    ()
        (( properties.loggregator_endpoint.shared_secret ))     in dynaml       config_from_cf.loggregator_endpoint.shared_secret       ()
        (( properties.nats.machines ))  in dynaml       config_from_cf.nats.machines    ()
        (( properties.nats.password ))  in dynaml       config_from_cf.nats.password    ()
        (( properties.nats.user ))      in dynaml       config_from_cf.nats.user        ()
        (( properties.system_domain ))  in dynaml       config_from_cf.system_domain    ()
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    name    (name)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.etcd.machines        (properties.etcd.machines)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.loggregator_endpoint.shared_secret   (properties.loggregator_endpoint.shared_secret)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.nats.password        (properties.nats.password)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.nats.user    (properties.nats.user)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.nats.machines        (properties.nats.machines)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.system_domain        (properties.system_domain)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.cc.internal_api_password     (properties.cc.internal_api_password)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.cc.srv_api_uri       (properties.cc.srv_api_uri)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.cc.staging_upload_password   (properties.cc.staging_upload_password)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.cc.staging_upload_user       (properties.cc.staging_upload_user)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.consul.agent.log_level       (properties.consul.agent.log_level)
        (( merge ))     in input/config-from-cf-internal.yml    properties.consul.agent.servers.lan     (properties.consul.agent.servers.lan)
```

Contents of the files I use for spiff merge.

config-from-cf.yml:

```
config_from_cf:
  cf_deployment_name: (( merge ))
  cc:
    internal_api_password: (( merge ))
    srv_api_uri: (( merge ))
    staging_upload_user: (( merge ))
    staging_upload_password: (( merge ))
  consul:
    log_level: (( merge ))
    lan_servers: (( merge ))
    ca_cert: (( merge ))
    agent_cert: (( merge ))
    agent_key: (( merge ))
    encrypt_keys: (( merge ))
    require_ssl: (( merge ))
    server_cert: (( merge ))
    server_key: (( merge ))
  etcd:
    machines: (( merge ))
  loggregator_endpoint:
    shared_secret: (( merge ))
  nats:
    user: (( merge ))
    password: (( merge ))
    port: (( merge ))
    machines: (( merge ))
  system_domain: (( merge ))
  uaa:
    clients:
      ssh-proxy:
        secret: (( merge ))
    url: (( merge || nil ))
```

config-from-cf-internal.yml:

```
config_from_cf:
  cf_deployment_name: (( name ))
  cc:
    internal_api_password: (( properties.cc.internal_api_password ))
    srv_api_uri: (( properties.cc.srv_api_uri ))
    staging_upload_user: (( properties.cc.staging_upload_user ))
    staging_upload_password: (( properties.cc.staging_upload_password ))
  consul:
    log_level: (( properties.consul.agent.log_level ))
    lan_servers: (( properties.consul.agent.servers.lan ))
    ca_cert: (( properties.consul.ca_cert ))
    agent_cert: (( properties.consul.agent_cert ))
    agent_key: (( properties.consul.agent_key ))
    encrypt_keys: (( properties.consul.encrypt_keys ))
    require_ssl: (( properties.consul.require_ssl ))
    server_cert: (( properties.consul.server_cert ))
    server_key: (( properties.consul.server_key ))
  etcd:
    machines: (( properties.etcd.machines ))
  loggregator_endpoint:
    shared_secret: (( properties.loggregator_endpoint.shared_secret ))
  nats:
    user: (( properties.nats.user ))
    password: (( properties.nats.password ))
    port: 4222
    machines: (( properties.nats.machines ))
  system_domain: (( properties.system_domain ))
  uaa:
    url: (( properties.uaa.url ))
    clients:
      ssh-proxy:
        secret: (( properties.uaa.clients.ssh-proxy.secret ))

# The keys below should not be included in the final stub
name: (( merge ))
properties:
  cc:
    internal_api_password: (( merge ))
    srv_api_uri: (( merge ))
    staging_upload_user: (( merge ))
    staging_upload_password: (( merge ))
  consul:
    agent:
      log_level: (( merge ))
      servers:
        lan: (( merge ))
    ca_cert:
    agent_cert:
    agent_key:
    encrypt_keys:
    require_ssl:
    server_cert:
    server_key:
  etcd:
    machines: (( merge ))
  loggregator_endpoint:
    shared_secret: (( merge ))
  nats:
    user: (( merge ))
    password: (( merge ))
    machines: (( merge ))
  system_domain: (( merge ))
  uaa:
    clients:
      ssh-proxy:
        secret: (( merge || nil ))
    url: (( merge || nil ))
```

cf-deployment.yml

```
#######################################################################
####### VARIABLES
#######################################################################
<%
director_uuid = 'XXX'
static_ip = 'XXX'
root_domain = "#{static_ip}.XXX"
cf_deployment_name = 'XXX'
cf_release_name = 'XXX'
cf_release_version = '0.0.1'
protocol = 'http'

flavorSmall = 'c1.medium'
flavorMedium = 'c1.large'
flavorLarge = 'c1.xlarge'
flavorXlarge = 'c1.xxlarge'

networkInternal = 'XXX'
networkInternalId = 'XXX'
networkInternalCIDR = 'XXX'
networkInternalGateway = 'XXX'
networkInternalSubnetId = 'XXX'
networkInternalDNS = ''

networkExternal = 'XXX'
networkExternalId = 'XXX'
networkExternalSubnetId = 'XXX'
networkExternalCIDR = 'XXX'
networkExternalGateway = 'XXX'
networkExternalDNS = 'XXX, XXX'

networkPublic = 'public'
networkPublicId = 'XXX'

IpInternalPostgres = 'XXX'
IpInternalRouter = 'XXX'
IpInternalNats = 'XXX'
IpInternalEtcd = 'XXX'
IpInternalNfs = 'XXX'
IpInternalConsul1 = 'XXX'
IpInternalConsul2 = 'XXX'
IpInternalConsul3 = 'XXX'

boshStemcell = 'bosh-openstack-kvm-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent-raw'


jobs_doppler_shared_secret = 'XXX'
jobs_uaa_admin_client_secret = 'XXX'
jobs_uaa_batch_password = 'XXX'
jobs_uaa_cc_client_secret = 'XXX'
jobs_uaa_scim_cc_client_secret = 'XXX'

properties_cc_db_encryption_key = 'XXX'
properties_cc_bulk_api_password = 'XXX'
properties_cc_internal_api_password = 'XXX'
properties_cc_staging_upload_password = 'XXX'

uaa_clients_cc_service_dashboards_password = 'XXX'
uaa_clients_cloud_controller_username_lookup_password = 'XXX'
uaa_clients_cc_routing_password = 'XXX'
uaa_clients_gorouter_password = 'XXX'
uaa_clients_login_password = 'XXX'
uaa_clients_servicesmgmt_password = 'XXX'

nats_password = 'XXX'
ccdb_roles_ccadmin_password = 'XXX'
ccdb_roles_uaaadmin_password = 'XXX'
loggregator_endpoint_shared_secret = 'XXX'
metron_endpoint_shared_secret = 'XXX'

%>
---


#######################################################################
####### NETWORK AND MISCELLANEOUS
#######################################################################



name: <%= cf_deployment_name %>
director_uuid: <%= director_uuid %>

releases:
- {name: <%= cf_release_name %>, version: <%= cf_release_version %>}

networks:
  - name: <%= networkInternal %>
    type: manual
    subnets:
    - range: <%= networkInternalCIDR %>
      gateway: <%= networkInternalGateway %>
      dns: [<%= networkInternalDNS %>]
      reserved: ["XXX - XXX"]
      static: ["XXX - XXX"]
      cloud_properties:
        net_id: <%= networkInternalId %> 
        security_groups:
        - default
        - XXX
        - XXX
        subnet: networkInternalSubnetId

  - name: <%= networkExternal %>
    type: manual
    subnets:
    - range: <%= networkExternalCIDR %>
      gateway: <%= networkExternalGateway %>
      dns: [<%= networkExternalDNS %>]
      reserved: ["XXX - XXX"]
      static: ["XXX - XXX"]
      cloud_properties:
        net_id: <%= networkExternalId %>
        security_groups:
          - default
          - XXX
          - XXX
          - XXX
        subnet: <%= networkExternalSubnetId %> 

  - name: <%= networkPublic %>
    type: vip
    cloud_properties:
      subnet: []

resource_pools:
  - name: common_z1
    network: <%= networkInternal %>
    stemcell:
      name: <%= boshStemcell  %>
      version: latest
    cloud_properties:
      instance_type: <%= flavorSmall %>

  - name: large_z1
    network: <%= networkInternal %>
    stemcell:
      name: <%= boshStemcell  %>
      version: latest
    cloud_properties:
      instance_type: <%= flavorMedium %>

compilation:
  workers: 2
  network: <%= networkInternal %>
  reuse_compilation_vms: true
  cloud_properties:
    instance_type: <%= flavorMedium %>

update:
  canaries: 1
  max_in_flight: 32
  serial: false
  canary_watch_time: 30000-600000
  update_watch_time: 30000-600000


#######################################################################
####### JOBS
#######################################################################

jobs:
   - name: nats_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
       - {name: nats, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: nats_stream_forwarder, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
       - name: <%= networkInternal %>
         static_ips: [<%= IpInternalNats %>]

   - name: etcd_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     persistent_disk: 102400
     templates:
     - {name: etcd, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     - {name: etcd_metrics_server, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
     - name: <%= networkInternal %>
       static_ips: [<%= IpInternalEtcd %>]
     properties:
      etcd_metrics_server:
        nats:
         machines: [<%= IpInternalNats %>]
         password: <%= nats_password %>
         username: nats

   - name: nfs_z1
     instances: 1
     persistent_disk: 102400
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
       - {name: debian_nfs_server, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
       - name: <%= networkInternal %>
         static_ips: [<%= IpInternalNfs %>]

   - name: postgres_z1
     instances: 1
     persistent_disk: 1024
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
     - {name: postgres, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
     - name: <%= networkInternal %>
       static_ips: [<%= IpInternalPostgres %>]
     update:
      serial: true

   - name: api_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
       - {name: cloud_controller_ng, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: cloud_controller_worker, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: cloud_controller_clock, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: nfs_mounter, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: route_registrar, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: consul_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
      - name: <%= networkInternal %>
     properties:
      nfs_server:
        address: <%= IpInternalNfs %>
        allow_from_entries: [<%= networkInternalCIDR %>]
      route_registrar:
        routes:
        - name: api
          port: 9022
          uris:
            - "api.<%= root_domain %>" 

   - name: ha_proxy_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
      - {name: haproxy, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
      - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
      - name: <%= networkPublic %>
        static_ips: [<%= static_ip %>]
      - name: <%= networkExternal %>
        default: [gateway, dns]
     properties:
       ha_proxy:
         ssl_pem: |
          -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
          XXX
          -----END CERTIFICATE-----
          -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
          XXX
          -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
       router:
         servers:
           z1: [<%= IpInternalRouter %>]

   - name: hm9000_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates: 
      - {name: hm9000, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
      - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
      - {name: route_registrar, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
      - name: <%= networkInternal %>
     properties:
      route_registrar:
        routes:
        - name: hm9000
          port: 5155
          uris:
            - "hm9000.<%= root_domain %>"

   - name: doppler_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
      - {name: doppler, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
      - name: <%= networkInternal %>
     properties:
      doppler: {zone: z1}
      doppler_endpoint:
        shared_secret: <%= jobs_doppler_shared_secret %>

   - name: loggregator_trafficcontroller_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
      - {name: loggregator_trafficcontroller, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
      - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
      - {name: route_registrar, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
      - name: <%= networkInternal %>
     properties:
       traffic_controller: {zone: z1}
       route_registrar:
        routes:
          - name: doppler
            port: 8081
            uris:
              - "doppler.<%= root_domain %>"
          - name: loggregator
            port: 8080
            uris:
              - "loggregator.<%= root_domain %>"

   - name: uaa_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
       - {name: uaa, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: route_registrar, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
      - name: <%= networkInternal %>
     properties:
      login:
        catalina_opts: -Xmx768m #-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
      route_registrar:
        routes:
        - name: uaa
          port: 8080
          uris:
            - "uaa.<%= root_domain %>"
            - "*.uaa.<%= root_domain %>"
            - "login.<%= root_domain %>"
            - "*.login.<%= root_domain %>"
      uaa:
        admin:
         client_secret: <%= jobs_uaa_admin_client_secret %>
        batch:
         password: <%= jobs_uaa_batch_password %>
         username: batch_user
        cc:
         client_secret: <%= jobs_uaa_cc_client_secret %>
        scim:
         userids_enabled: true
         users:
           - admin|<%= jobs_uaa_scim_cc_client_secret %>|scim.write,scim.read,openid,cloud_controller.admin,doppler.firehose
      uaadb:
        address: <%= IpInternalPostgres %>
        databases:
          - {name: uaadb, tag: uaa}
        db_scheme: postgresql
        port: 5524
        roles:
          - {name: uaaadmin, password: <%= ccdb_roles_uaaadmin_password %>, tag: admin}

   - name: router_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
       - {name: gorouter, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
      - name: <%= networkInternal %>
        static_ips: [<%= IpInternalRouter %>]
     properties:
      dropsonde: {enabled: true}

   - name: runner_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
       - {name: dea_next, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: dea_logging_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
       - name: <%= networkInternal %>
     properties:
      dea_next: {zone: z1}

   - name: stats_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     templates:
       - {name: collector, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
       - {name: metron_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}
     networks:
       - name: <%= networkInternal %>
     properties:
      collector: {deployment_name: <%= cf_deployment_name %>}

   - name: consul_z1
     instances: 1
     resource_pool: common_z1
     networks:
      - name: <%= networkInternal %>
        static_ips: [<%= IpInternalConsul1 %>]
     templates: 
       - {name: consul_agent, release: <%= cf_release_name %>}

#   - name: consul_z2
#     instances: 0
#     networks:
#      - name: <%= networkExternal %>
#        static_ips: []

#######################################################################
####### Properties
#######################################################################

properties:
  networks: {apps: <%= networkInternal %>}
  app_domains: [<%= root_domain %>]

  cc:
    allow_app_ssh_access: false
    bulk_api_password: <%= properties_cc_bulk_api_password %>
    db_encryption_key: <%= properties_cc_db_encryption_key  %>
    default_running_security_groups: [public_networks, dns]
    default_staging_security_groups: [public_networks, dns]
    install_buildpacks:
    - {name: java_buildpack, package: buildpack_java}
    - {name: ruby_buildpack, package: buildpack_ruby}
    - {name: nodejs_buildpack, package: buildpack_nodejs}
    - {name: go_buildpack, package: buildpack_go}
    - {name: python_buildpack, package: buildpack_python}
    - {name: php_buildpack, package: buildpack_php}
    - {name: staticfile_buildpack, package: buildpack_staticfile}
    - {name: binary_buildpack, package: buildpack_binary}
    internal_api_password: <%= properties_cc_internal_api_password  %>
    quota_definitions:
      default:
        memory_limit: 4000 #MB
        non_basic_services_allowed: false
        total_routes: 20
        total_services: -1
      iron_quota:
        memory_limit: 8000 #MB
        non_basic_services_allowed: false
        total_routes: 100
        total_services: 40
      bronze_quota:
        memory_limit: 16000 #MB
        non_basic_services_allowed: false
        total_routes: 300
        total_services: 300
      silver_quota:
        memory_limit: 32000 #MB
        non_basic_services_allowed: false
        total_routes: 1000
        total_services: 1000
      gold_quota:
        memory_limit: 64000 #MB
        non_basic_services_allowed: true
        total_routes: 5000
        total_services: 2000
        trial_db_allowed: true
    security_group_definitions:
    - name: public_networks
      rules:
      - {destination: XXX-XXX, protocol: all}
      - {destination: XXX-XXX, protocol: all}
      - {destination: XXX-XXX, protocol: all}
      - {destination: XXX-XXX, protocol: all}
      - {destination: XXX-XXX, protocol: all}
    - name: dns
      rules:
      - {destination: XXX, ports: '53', protocol: tcp}
      - {destination: XXX, ports: '53', protocol: udp}
    srv_api_uri: http://api.<%= root_domain %>
    staging_upload_password: <%= properties_cc_staging_upload_password %>
    staging_upload_user: staging_upload_user

  ccdb:
    address: <%= IpInternalPostgres %>
    databases:
    - {name: ccdb, tag: cc}
    db_scheme: postgres
    port: 5524
    roles:
    - {name: ccadmin, password: <%= ccdb_roles_ccadmin_password %>, tag: admin}

  databases:
    databases:
    - {name: ccdb, tag: cc, citext: true}
    - {name: uaadb, tag: uaa, citext: true}
    port: 5524
    roles:
    - {name: ccadmin, password: <%= ccdb_roles_ccadmin_password %>, tag: admin}
    - {name: uaaadmin, password: <%= ccdb_roles_uaaadmin_password %>, tag: admin}

  dea_next:
    advertise_interval_in_seconds: 5
    heartbeat_interval_in_seconds: 10
    memory_mb: 33996

  description: XXX

  domain: <%= root_domain %>

  etcd:
    machines: [<%= IpInternalEtcd %>]

  hm9000:
    url: http://hm9000.<%= root_domain %>

  logger_endpoint:
    port: 4443

  loggregator_endpoint:
    shared_secret: <%= loggregator_endpoint_shared_secret %>

  login:
    protocol: http

  metron_agent:
    zone: z1
    deployment: minimal-aws

  metron_endpoint:
    shared_secret: <%= metron_endpoint_shared_secret %>

  nats:
    machines: [<%= IpInternalNats %>]
    password: <%= nats_password %>
    port: 4222
    user: nats

  nfs_server:
    address: <%= IpInternalNfs %>
    allow_from_entries: [<%= networkInternalCIDR %>]

  ssl:
    skip_cert_verify: true

  system_domain: <%= root_domain %>

  system_domain_organization: default_organization

  uaa:
    clients:
      cc-service-dashboards:
        authorities: clients.read,clients.write,clients.admin
        authorized-grant-types: client_credentials
        scope: openid,cloud_controller_service_permissions.read
        secret: <%= uaa_clients_cc_service_dashboards_password %>
      cloud_controller_username_lookup:
        authorities: scim.userids
        authorized-grant-types: client_credentials
        secret: <%= uaa_clients_cloud_controller_username_lookup_password %>
      cc_routing:
        authorities: routing.router_groups.read
        secret: <%= uaa_clients_cc_routing_password %>
        authorized-grant-types: client_credentials
      gorouter:
        authorities: clients.read,clients.write,clients.admin,routing.routes.write,routing.routes.read
        authorized-grant-types: client_credentials,refresh_token
        scope: openid,cloud_controller_service_permissions.read
        secret: <%= uaa_clients_gorouter_password %>
      doppler:
        authorities: uaa.resource
        secret: <%= jobs_doppler_shared_secret %>
      login:
        authorities: oauth.login,scim.write,clients.read,notifications.write,critical_notifications.write,emails.write,scim.userids,password.write
        authorized-grant-types: authorization_code,client_credentials,refresh_token
        redirect-uri: http://login.<%= root_domain %>
        scope: openid,oauth.approvals
        secret: <%= uaa_clients_login_password %>
      servicesmgmt:
        authorities: uaa.resource,oauth.service,clients.read,clients.write,clients.secret
        authorized-grant-types: authorization_code,client_credentials,password,implicit
        autoapprove: true
        redirect-uri: http://servicesmgmt.<%= root_domain %>/auth/cloudfoundry/callback
        scope: openid,cloud_controller.read,cloud_controller.write
        secret: <%= uaa_clients_servicesmgmt_password %>
    jwt:
      signing_key: |
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        XXX
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      verification_key: |
        -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
        XXX
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    no_ssl: true
    url: http://uaa.<%= root_domain %>

  consul:
    encrypt_keys:
      - XXX
    require_ssl: true
    ca_cert: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      XXX
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    server_cert: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      XXX
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    server_key: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      XXX
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    agent_cert: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      XXX
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    agent_key: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      XXX
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML is getting confused with all your variables at the top, followed by `---`.  It sees it as a document separator, so essentially only the stuff above the `---` is being read.  You can read more about YAML document separators [here](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#trailing_document_separator).

If you delete everything above the first triple-dash, you will get further with your spiff merge, however you will still fail due to missing `consul` properties. So you will at least need to add those in.

Even then, you will have problems, because you are intended to use this tool with a fully resolved CF deployment manifest as the third argument, not something that still has ERB in it (the ERB variable assignments in your `input/cf-deployment.yml` will not be carried over to `output/config-from-cf.yml`. If you have already done `bosh deploy` with your CF manifest that still has ERB in it, you can pull down a resolved version from the BOSH directory by doing `bosh download manifest XXX input/resolved-cf-deployment.yml` and then run:

```
spiff merge input/config-from-cf.yml \
            input/config-from-cf-internal.yml \
            input/resolved-cf-deployment.yml \
            > output/config-from-cf.yml
```

Comment: Great answer. Gives a lot of insight. I find it a pity that I can't centrally define data that I use multiple times. Or is this possible in a useful way?